# Bash - one liner to sort a bed file on qvalue column then extract top 20% of rows with highest q value

Tags: r, bash, sorting, filtering, percentage

I have a bed file in the following format:

```
chr start   end q-value   name
chr1    10004  10467    310.43    peak_1
chr2    15410  15704    19.61 peak_2
chr3    21207  21354    4.04  peak_3
chr4    26073  26165    25.32 peak_4
chr5   63044057  63044425   39.65  peak_5
```

If possible, I need a bash one-liner to sort this file on the q-value column (column 4), then I need to extract the top 20% of rows with the highest q-value.

After sorting this would look like:

```
chr start   end q-value   name
chr1    10004  10467    310.43    peak_1
chr5   63044057  63044425   39.65  peak_5
chr4   26073  26165    25.32 peak_4
chr2    15410  15704    19.61 peak_2
chr3    21207  21354    4.04  peak_3
```

After percentage it would look like:

```
chr1    10004  10467    310.43    peak_1
```

I need to run this on over 40 files.

I'm also familiar with R so if this is not possible in bash, but doable in R, R code would also be useful (but Bash is preferable).

Many Thanks.

---

**Edit comments:**

Made code more testable.

Re: my own attempt

When I tried to run `sort -k4 file.txt` in the first instance. I got the following which is not what I'm looking for:

```
chr2    15410  15704    19.61 peak_2
chr4    26073  26165    25.32 peak_4
chr1    10004  10467    310.43    peak_1
chr5   63044057  63044425   39.65  peak_5
chr3    21207  21354    4.04  peak_3
```

This confused me, I assume the decimals are causing an issue and not sure how to get round this first part.

Comment: What efforts did you make? Can you also post a more testable input? We can't work _imagining_ the data on column 9

Comment: What is your attempt?

Comment: Have a look at `sort`. Maybe something like `sort -nk10`. Then pipe into `head` and tell us how it went.

Comment: @Darren, please add expected output in your post too with CODE TAGS.

Comment: `wc -l` can be used to count rows, and percentages can be calculated natively, as there's no gain in floating point arithmetic in this case.

Comment: @Inian - Added testable input
@RavinderSingh13 - added expected output @AkselA I - tried your`sort -nk10 suggestion but this didn't sort as I expected. Updated my original post to make what I'm looking for more explicit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking at?

```
#!/bin/sh
sort -r -g -k 4,4 < inputFile.file > tempfile_sorted.out
lncnt=$(wc -l < tempfile_sorted.out)
percent_linecount_infloat=$(echo "$lncnt*.2" | bc)
float2Int=$(printf %.0f "$percent_linecount_infloat")
head_20_percent=$(head -"$float2Int" tempfile_sorted.out)
new_fn=$(printf "%s_20" tempfile_sorted.out) # new file with top 20% of sorted output
printf "$head_20_percent" > $new_fn
```